# Style for android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Does anyone know the style resource to use for the split action bar when using sdk version 14 `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` ?

For the normal `ActionBar` I can use

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

But this does not automatically overflow to the split bar at the bottom.

I have tried

```
    <item name="android:actionBarSplitStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

But they both have no effect on the Galaxy Nexus

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer is basically [niko34's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328152/niko34) but in a little bit more detail. Currently I have both the top actionbar and the lower actionbar (the lower actionbar is more properly named as the [split actionbar](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar)) styled the same, but you'll see it's pretty darn simple to style them differently. I am using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) v4.2.0, and have tested and run this flawlessly on both a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Jelly Bean and an HTC Droid Incredible running Gingerbread.

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="..."
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/main_activity_title"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### res/values/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Here you can see how I'm referencing `@drawable/bg_actionbar` a couple of times. That is an xml file that is located in the `res/drawable` directory. Below is the source of that file.

### res/drawable/bg_actionbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_tile"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Here, `android:src="@drawable/bg_tile"` is just referencing my `bg_tile.png` file, which is located in `res/drawable-hdpi`, `res/drawable-ldpi`, `res/drawable-mdpi`, and `res/drawable-xhdpi`.

So all of this was probably more information than necessary, but it's better than not having enough! :)

Comment: The split action bar doesn't work when there is map fragment :-/

Answer (score 4):

This question is old, but i've just handled the same problem. If it can help someone else...

The split bar is also styled using ActionBarStyle.

For example, if you want to style the bottom part of the split action bar, you can use the item named backgroundSplit in your MyActionBar style.

```
...
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
...

<style name="MyActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_top_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/action_bar_bottom_background</item>
</style>
```

you can use a style instead of the drawable to customize the backgrounds, but if prefer this  to define backgrounds in drawables.