# Where can I find the ActionBar OverFlow button icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I've been trying to create my own action bar, in order to have 2 actions bars.
Native one will be on bottom, and the custom one will be at the top.

I would like to have the OverFlow (the 3 dots button) button, that appears in the Native Action Bar, in my custom Action Bar.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to put my custom Action Bar on the bottom and the Native one on the top ?
2. If the answer to Q1 is no, then, is there a way to imitate the overflow buttons look and behavior ?

I would prefer to do it like Questions 1..

I've been searching for the the overflow button's Icon in the drawables - but couldn't find it.

I would appreciate any help or direction,

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you've changed the order that you said you want them.. native on top or bottom?

Comment: you have fumbled the question ! may be !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the native one will be at the top, and if you disable split-actionbar, there will be no action bar at the bottom. And of course it is possible to "simulate" an actionbar at the bottom of your application, by creating an action-bar-look-a-like manually.
2. Thought the answer to 1. is yes, It might be useful to someone else:

It's actually inside the android SDK, in platforms/android-XX/data/res/values/style.xml

The overflow menu's style definition:

```
 <style name="Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
     <item name="android:src">@android:drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark</item>
     <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
     <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/action_menu_overflow_description</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: You've said "yes" in 1), and then in 2) you say "no".

Comment: Sorry, my bad, changed it

Comment: now you have to wait for OP to clarify whether he meant he wants native on top or bottom, as he states both options :P

Comment: I would prefer to put my custom action bar on bottom. Is that possible ? I've searched for solution and couldn't find one.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "custom", custom styles, or just a bar that looks like an action bar? Anyways: https://www.google.com/search?q=action+bar+only+at+bottom

Comment: By custom I mean a custom view of action bar, set by actionBar.setCustomView() . About the button, I put this is my layout file: `<Button
      style="Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow"
      android:id="@+id/action_starred"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>` But this not working, it shows a transparent button with no 3 dots.

Comment: So you would like the default style action bar at the top, and a custom action bar at the bottom, both being a "official" actionbar?

Comment: Yes, both official, but I want to put the Native one on the top, and the custom on the bottom

Comment: Well, this answer describes how to style the top and bottom action bar differently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12963598/1683141